# Múltiples consultas en una vista

Tags: html, python, django, pdf

necesito solución a un pequeño problema, estoy tratando de renderizar dos objetos en un pdf, la aplicación trata de gestionar propiedades de clientes, obviamente cada cliente puede tener mas de una propiedad. A la hora de hacer la consulta solo me muestra el primer registro y los demás los omite.

Mi vista:

```
def pdf_generation(request, *args, **kwargs):
pk = kwargs.get('pk')
client = Client.objects.get(pk=pk)
farm = Farm.objects.filter(pk=pk)
context = {
    'client': client,
    'farm': farm,
}
html_string = render_to_string('client_pdf.html', context)
html = HTML(string=html_string, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri())
pdf = html.write_pdf(
    stylesheets=[CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/css/pdf.css')])
response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="export.pdf"'
return response
```

La url

```
    path('export/<int:pk>', views.pdf_generation, name='client_export_id'),
```

El html de client

```
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ client.id }}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{ client.name }}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{ client.nif }}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{ client.technical }}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{ client.phone }}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{ client.record|date:"j F, Y" }}</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Y el html de farm

```
        <tbody>
            {% for obj in farm %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ obj.id }}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{ obj.manager }}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{ obj.farm }}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{ obj.town }}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{ obj.place }}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{ obj.production }}</th>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Esto es "Stackoverflow en Español" This is "Stackoverflow en Español"

Comment: Listo, lo siento pensé que estaba en stackoverflow internacional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que un client tiene una o mas farms, si es asi:

la view cambiaria estas lineas:

```py
client = Client.objects.get(pk=pk)
farm = Farm.objects.filter(pk=pk)
```

por algo asi:

```py
client = Client.objects.get(pk=pk)
farm = Farm.objects.filter(client=client)
```

o asi:

```py
client = Client.objects.get(pk=pk)
farm = client.farms.all()
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, al final revise mi archivo models.py y siguiendo tus instrucciones lo arregle. la opcion (client=client) me sirvio, solo que tuve que cambiar uno de los client por name como lo tengo en mi modelo. Saludos y muchas gracias.